# How to check if a date is in the future

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I want to make a spreadsheet reporting daily and weekly goals for a certain quantity and their achievement, one reporting sheet per calendar week. Imagine that I open it on Wednesday, then I want to see:

```
                         | Goal   | Actual | Overfulfilment | Deficit | 
 May 6, 2013 | Monday    | 100    | 110    | 10             |         |
 May 7, 2013 | Tuesday   | 100    | 95     |                |       5 |
 May 8, 2013 | Wednesday | 100    | 50     |                |      50 |
 May 9, 2013 | Thursday  | 100    |        |                |         |
May 10, 2013 | Friday    | 100    |        |                |         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                            current fulfilment |  -45 |
                                               week fulfilment | -245 |
```

The number in "current fulfilment" is the sum of the overfulfilment on Monday and the deficit on Tuesday and Wednesday, telling us how much we deviate from the quantity we should have produced until the end of the current day. The number in "week fulfilment" is the sum of goals for the whole week minus the production thus far, telling us how much we need to produce until the end of the week.

In order to calculate this, I wanted to use `DATEDIF(A5, TODAY(), "d")`
and check for negativity, then only calculate the sum for current fulfilment where the result is negative. Sadly, DATEDIF gives me an error instead of a negative difference.

Is there an easy way to perform this check so I can calculate my current fulfilment dependent on when the sheet is opened?

Comment: I would use Python to make a macro to do this.

Comment: In Excel you can use arithmetic operations on dates, I do not know if they work in libre-office.  I can simply do `=IF(A2>$B$1,"Future","Past")` (where B1 contains todays date) to find out if the day is in the future or past, then I can do `=$B$1-A4` to get the number of days in the future or past.  Do either of these work in Libreoffice Calc?

Comment: Additionally Excel at least fails to understand your date format, what happens if you change the date to 07/05/13 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Using DATEDIF it appears that you are using it to determine if it is a future (negative) date?

So how about something like this:
`=IF(A5 > TODAY(), sum(columns), "FALSE")`